# Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality in a $C^∗$-algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am trying to prove the following lemma:

> Let $\omega$ be a positive linear functional over the $^*$-algebra
>   $\mathfrak{A}$. It follows that \begin{align*} \text{(a)}\quad &
>  \omega(A^*B)=\overline{\omega(B^*A)}, \\ \text{(b)}\quad &
>  |\omega(A^*B)|^2 \le \omega(A^*A)\omega(B^*B) \quad \forall A,B \in
> > \mathfrak{A}. \\ \end{align*}

The proof is pretty straightforward. In essence, it is similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699933/cauchy-schwarz-in-complex-case-using-discriminant).

For $A,B \in \mathfrak{A}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C},$ positivity of $\omega$ implies that

$$ \omega((\lambda A + B)^*(\lambda A + B)) \ge 0 $$

Please note that this is a partial ordering in the complex plane: $\text{For } a,b \in \mathbb{C},$ $a \le b \iff \mathcal{Re}(a-b) \le 0 \ \land \ \mathcal{Im}(a-b) = 0 \,.$

By linearity this becomes

$$ |\lambda|^2 \omega(A^*A) + \overline{\lambda}\omega(A^*B) + \lambda \omega(B^*A) + \omega(B^*B) \ge 0$$

From here, (a) follows immediately. To prove (b), we note that the following matrix is self-adjoint.

$$ Q_{AB}(\lambda) := \begin{bmatrix}
    |\lambda|^2 \omega(A^*A)       & \lambda \omega(B^*A) \\
    \overline{\lambda}\omega(A^*B)       & \omega(B^*B) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Claim (b) follows straightforwardly from the non-negativity of $\mathrm{det}(Q_{AB}(\lambda)).$

So my question boils down to something altogether different. If a Hermitian matrix has non-negative diagonal entries, does it also have only non-negative eigenvalues?

If not, how should I end the above proof?

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ -2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$ has an eigenvalue of $-1$

Comment: @OfekGillon That's right. So how is it that the necessary, and sufficient, conditions for the positivity of the quadratic form in $\lambda$ are exactly the two conditions of the lemma?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: @MartinArgerami How can we prove claim (b) from the non-negativity of the quadratic form in $\lambda$?

Comment: Ok. I have written a proof. The matrix thing makes no sense to me, but I never paid much attention to quadratic forms per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to write the quadratic equation like this:
$$\tag{1}
|\lambda|^2 \omega(A^*A) +  2\text{Re}\, \lambda \omega(B^*A) + \omega(B^*B) \ge 0.
$$
It is important to notice that we are free to choose $\lambda$, and $A$ and $B$. Fix $A,B$. Let $\gamma\in\mathbb T$ such that $\gamma\,\omega(B^*A)=|\omega(B^*A)|$. Given $t\in \mathbb R$, put $\lambda=t\gamma$. Then $(1)$ becomes 
$$\tag{2}
t^2 \omega(A^*A) +  2t|\omega(B^*A)| + \omega(B^*B) \ge 0
$$
As we can do this for any $t\in\mathbb R$ and this is a real quadratic, for this to be always non-negative we need "$b^2\leq 4ac"$, i.e., 
$$
4|\omega(B^*A)|^2\leq 4|\omega(A^*A)|\,|\omega(B^*B)|.
$$

Comment: What is $\mathbb T$? Moreover, don't you need "$b^2 -4ac \ge 0$" for real solutions?

Comment: $\mathbb T$ is the unit circle. If $b^2-4ac>0$, the quadratic has two roots and so it cannot be always positive.

Comment: But isn't it worse if the roots are not even real? Sorry, I must be missing something basic.

Comment: I suggest you draw a parabola and think about the roots.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help.