# What is the norm of a dynamical state on a C*-algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $(\mathcal A, \tau)$ be a $C^*$-dynamical system and let $\omega$ be a state on $\mathcal A$.

Is the following true, and if yes, why?

$$ |\omega(\tau_t(A)| \le \|A\| \quad \forall t \in \mathbb R, A \in \mathcal A $$

---

I have a hunch why it should be true for a concrete example.

If the dynamics is given by a Hamiltonian $H$, that is

$$ \tau_t(A) := e^{itH} A e^{-itH} \,,$$

then the result follows from the formula

$$ \omega(B^*AB) \le \omega(B^*B)\|A\| $$

replacing $B$ with $e^{-itH}$.

However, even in this concrete example, I am not sure if $e^{-itH}$ belongs to the algebra $\mathcal A$, given that the Hamiltonian $H$ is already in the algebra. I think it has to do with the fact that $\mathcal A$ is a Banach space by definition. Therefore, the convergent exponential series should have a limit point in the algebra. Right?

Nevertheless, this is just a hunch with a concrete example. I would like to know the more general theorem stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A state by definition has norm $1$, and $\tau_t$ is an automorphism for all $t$, hence isometric (any injective $*$-homomorphism between $C^*$-algebras is isometric, see [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3185381/injective-homomorphism-is-isometric)).  Thus we have
$$|\omega\tau_tA|\leq\|\omega\|\|\tau_tA\|=\|\tau_tA\|=\|A\|.$$

Comment: I think the first inequality should read: $|\omega\tau_tA|^2 \leq \|\omega\| \omega ( \tau_t (A^*A) ).$ How do you see that $\omega ( \tau_t (A^*A) ) = \|\tau_tA\|^2\,?$

Comment: $\omega$ is a bounded linear functional, hence $|\omega A|\leq\|\omega\|\|A\|$ for all $A$.  Now replace $A$ with $\tau_t A$.

Comment: How do you see that $|\omega A|\leq\|\omega\|\|A\|$? From the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in a $C^∗$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2268223/404320), one can only conclude that $|\omega A|^2 \leq \|\omega\| \omega ( A^*A ).$ Note that only for a specific *pure* state, it holds that $\omega ( A^*A ) = \|A\|^2.$

Comment: This has nothing to do with $\omega$ being positve, just that it is a bounded linear functional.  Remember back from functional analysis.

Comment: Okay, if I take your word for it, I am safe to use intuition from functional analysis. So just to be clear, does this mean the equality $\omega ( A^*A ) = \|A\|^2$ is **always** true (for consistency, of course), irrespective of whether or not the state is pure? But my book has lemma on exactly when this equality holds (depending on whether or not the state is pure). What is going on? Thank you very much.

Comment: No.  For a state we would have $\omega(A^*A)\leq\|\omega\|\|A^*A\|=\|A^*A\|=\|A\|^2$, but equality cannot be proven.

Comment: Clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.