# Injective $*$-homomorphism is isometric

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am aware there are other proofs of line of this statement. But I am interested in the argument outlined here on [page 62-63](https://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/bruceb/Cycr.pdf)

> **Corollary II.2.2.9** Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^*$ algebras, $\phi:A \rightarrow B$ be injective $*$-homomoprhism. Then $\phi$ is isometric, i.e. $||\phi(x) || = ||x||$ for all $x \in A$.

The proof goes as follows: Wlog we may assume $A,B$ are commutative (I got this ), and it is obvious from II.2.2.4. (as below).

> **Theorem II.2.2.4**  If $A$ is a commutative $C^*$ algebra, then the Gelfand trasform is an isometric $*$-isomorphism from $A$ onto $C_0(\hat{A})$.

---

How does II.2.2.4 imply 2.2.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be II.2.2.4, the Gelfand Transform, a few theorems back. If you are new to C$^*$-algebras, reading Blackadar (with almost no proofs and a general point of view) is probably not the best idea.

Answer to the edit: as Blackadar says, the C$^*$-identity lets you restrict the problem to $A,B$ abelian. So you have maps 
$$
C_0(\hat A)\xrightarrow{\ \ \ \ \ } A\xrightarrow{\ \ \phi\ \ } B\xrightarrow{\ \ \ \ \ } C_0(\hat B),
$$
where the three maps are injective ($\phi$ by hypothesis and the other two by II.2.2.4). Now when restricted to algebras of continuous functions you can use II.2.2.5/II.2.2.7: say $\psi:C(X)\to C(Y)$ is an injective homomorphism. Then $\breve\psi:Y\to X$ is surjective. Now, for $f\in C(X)$, you have (I do the compact case to avoid a few epsilons)
$$
\|f\|=|f(x_1)|=|f(\breve\psi (y_1))|=|(\psi f)(y_1)|\leq \|\psi f\|. 
$$
Also, 
$$
\|\psi f\|=|(\psi f)(y_0)|=|f(\breve\psi(y_0))|\leq \|f\|. 
$$
Thus $\|f\|=\|\psi f\|$.

Comment: That's the only part of the proof that Blackadar **did** write!

Comment: No, he says "For the first part, it remains only to
show that $\Gamma$ is isometric (then the range will be closed, hence all of $C_0(\tilde A)$ by
the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem). By the C$^*$-axiom and II.1.6.6., it suffices to
show that if $x = x^∗$, then $\|\hat x\|\geq\|x\|$. By II.2.1.2. there is $λ \in \sigma_A(x)$ with $|λ| = \|x\|$, so there is a φ with $|\tilde x(φ)| = \|x\|$."

Comment: Edited. The "theorem" in the "obvious" statement is II.2.2.8 and not II.2.2.4.

Comment: I mean - how did you get the last $\le$ for both of your lines?

Comment: They are points. The norm of a function $f$ is $\|f\|=\max\{|f(t)|: t\}$. So you always have $|f(t)|\leq \|f\|$.

Comment: I see ! Thanks a lot. I thought you meant operator, now everything makes sense.

Comment: Glad I could help. That was the whole point of the move to C$^*$-algebras of continuous functions.

Comment: Hi Martin, I wonder if you know a reference/ proof of the more general statement for the post here on ess. s.a. operators. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183960/decomposition-for-essentially-self-adjoint-operators

Comment: I know very little about unbounded operators, so I'm not sure I can help.

Comment: Ok, you have helped a lot already. I also have one, that requires little no knowledge : i just want to apply functional calculus but do not get the desired conclusion. I wonder if you can have a look at where I got wrong. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3185681/applying-functional-calculus-to-the-bounded-operator-t-pm-ii-1

Comment: Why can you focus on commutative $C^*$-algebras? How does the $C^*$-identity allow restriction?

Comment: Since $\|a\|=\|a^*a\|^{1/2}$, it is enough to prove that $\phi$ is isometric on positive elements. So one considers the restriction of $\phi$ to $C^*(a)$ for $a\geq0$, which is abelian. And the image of an abelian C$^*$-algebra through a $*$-homomorphism is abelian.